# Angular dynamic component loses style when embedded in iframe

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I need to get a dynamic component to embed in an iframe.  The only approach I have seen to accomplish this uses createComponent to dynamically generate a new instance of the given component, and then moves it into the body of the iframe.

The problem with this approach is no styles carry over because the dynamic component is generated in the parent page and copied over - but, the styles are injected in the head of the parent page and don't go with it.

My thinking is the way to resolve this is either come up with a way to manually migrate the generated styles into the iframe or to somehow generate the component within the iframe itself so that the styles get rendered inside.

Here's an example of the issue:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajo1gy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated!  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can get styles related to component so you're left with:

- creating style object ( bad idea though )

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // get reference to loaded iframe document
      this.frameDoc =
      this.contentFrame.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
      this.contentFrame.nativeElement.contentWindow;
      this.frameDoc.body.appendChild(this.contentRef.location.nativeElement);
      const style = document.createElement("style");
      style.innerHTML = `
      h1 {
        color: blue;
      }
      `;
      this.frameDoc.body.appendChild(style);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

- use [single style binding or ngStyles on h1 element](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-style-attribute) and hope `this.contentRef.location.nativeElement` will contain computed inline style once its in iframe ( didn't test that out).

```js
@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `<h1 [style.color]="'blue'">Content Window - I should be blue</h1>`
})
export class HelloComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <h1 [ngStyle]="{'color': 'blue'}">Content Window - I should be blue</h1>`,
})
export class HelloComponent {}
```

Comment: I had mixed results with different approaches, especially across different browsers and platforms.  In the end, I just went with inline styles in the template itself with template interpolation to getters where dynamic values were needed.  

Not the cleanest approach, but if you're already using iframes to hide alternate templates, I guess you are already down the rabbit hole.