# How to load completely an Angular component into an iframe?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to load a complex component to an iframe (component called other components). I've done to load it using `ComponentFactoryResolver` but without any style.

From this topic: [How do we load an angular component's styles into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717120/how-do-we-load-an-angular-components-styles-into-an-iframe)

When using `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, it just works for the internal styles of that component, the global styles couldn't apply anymore.
The more thing is I can't modify the children component (from libraries, from codebases, etc.. that I can't modify).

Any better way to completely load a complex Angular component into an iframe?

This is the demo code in StackBliz: [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7dbde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Using ShadowDom you are separating them one from each other. Can you share some stackblitz example so we can check it out.

Comment: @Bozhinovski updated StackBliz, you can check it out

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements). If applicable, it's better than using an iframe.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. no, it doesn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370641/12172540 @mikenlanggio could be the solution you're searching for.

Comment: @NadimAlAbdou Thank you, but you got wrong what I mean