# How to safely load a Component using Eval inside?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know the title might make you confuse.

I have a `ParentComponent` called `ChildComponent`.
`ChildComponent` using `eval` to do some stuff. And the worst thing is, the `eval`'s value can pass by users.
Maybe users will input some bad thing for the whole application, so I'm trying to prevent it.

The first solution that comes to my head is loading `ChildComponent` into an `iframe` (like a code-sandbox), so it can protect my Application (anything `eval` just affect the `iframe`).
But it has some problems: styles couldn't load correctly.
I asked about that problem but got no answer [How to load completely an Angular component into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72169512/how-to-load-completely-an-angular-component-into-an-iframe)

I'm stuck, any idea for my problem is really appreciate

Comment: What did you tried ? What worked, what didn't ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried using `iframe` but `styles` didn't work correctly.

Comment: Provide code, you maybe use the right component wrongly

Comment: Take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7dbde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72169512/how-to-load-completely-an-angular-component-into-an-iframe too
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, an iframe doesn't prevent anything.

You can just call `window.parent` to get a reference to the parent window.

Second, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) : do not ask for help on what YOU think is the best solution, but rather explain the goal you are trying to achieve.

Finally, know that eval will NEVER be safe, so you should use it at your own risk.

*But then again, JS as a whole is not safe, you can just open the dev tools and hack into any website.*